# WCF XML deserialization not populating array

Tags: c#, arrays, xml, wcf, serialization

I have developed a WCF using VS 2017 Pro (C#) targeting .Net 4.5.1
The service accepts an XML object in the SOAP request.
Problem I am having is that there is an array in the XML that is not deserializing.  The WCF is using the native deserializer.  Code & XML sample below.

XML tag Application->Amount deserializes ok

XML tag Application_SAList->Application_SA->SecurityKey> does not

business logic null check for ApplicationImpl.Application_SAList passes, but length of ApplicationImpl.Application_SAList.Application_SA array is 0

all classes have 'using System.Runtime.Serialization;'

Desperate to figure this out!  Thanks in advance for anyone's help!

IApplicationService.cs

```
namespace TApplicationService
{
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://xyz")]
    public interface IApplicationService
    {

        [OperationContract(Name="ProcessApplication")]
        string ProcessApplication(ApplicationRequestImpl ApplicationRequestImpl);
    }
}
```

ApplicationService.svc.cs

```
namespace ThriventApplicationService
{

    [ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://xyz")]
    public class ApplicationService : IApplicationService
    {
        private SDatabase gDatabase = null;

        public string ProcessApplication(ApplicationRequestImpl ApplicationRequestImpl)
        {
          // does a bunch of business logic here
        }
}
```

ApplicationRequestImpl.cs

```
namespace ThriventApplicationService
    {

        [DataContract(Namespace = "http://xyz")]
        public class ApplicationRequestImpl
        {
            [DataMember]
            public Application Application;

            [DataMember(Name="Application_SAList")]
            public ApplicationSASingle Application_SAList;
        }
    }
```

Application.cs

```
namespace ThriventApplicationService
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://xyz")]
    public class Application : IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        [DataMember]
        public string Amount;
    }
}
```

Application_SASingle.cs

```
namespace ThriventApplicationService
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://xyz")]
    public class ApplicationSASingle
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Application_SA[] Application_SA;
    }
}
```

Application_SA.cs

```
namespace ThriventApplicationService
{
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://xyz")]
    public class Application_SA
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Security_Key;
    }
}
```

SAMPLE XML

```
<ProcessApplication xmlns="http://xyz">
    <ApplicationRequestImpl>
        <Application>
            <Amount>50000.0</Amount>
        </Application>
        <Application_SAList>
            <Application_SA>
                <Security_Key>1588</Security_Key>
            </Application_SA>
        </Application_SAList>
    </ApplicationRequestImpl>
</ProcessApplication>
```

SOLUTION in ApplicationRequestImpl.cs

```
   [DataContract(Namespace = "http://prosurv")]
    public class ApplicationRequestImpl
    {

        [DataMember]
        public Application Application;

        [DataMember(Name="Application_SAList")]
        //public Application_SAList Application_SAList;
        public Application_SA[] Application_SA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After another shot I have found the solution. The problem is with `ApplicationRequestImpl` class. XML rerader is looking for `Application_SA` element inside `Application_SA` which doesn't exist.

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://xyz")]
public class ApplicationRequestImpl
{
    [DataMember]
    public Application Application;

    //Remove these two lines
    //[DataMember(Name="Application_SAList")]
    //public ApplicationSASingle Application_SAList;

    [DataMember]
    public Application_SA[] Application_SAList;
}
```

**Check [full working solution](https://github.com/dropoutcoder/datacontract-deserialization)**

---

<s>The problem with arrays is that they need know their size. Which during initialization is 0. Which equals to:</s>

```
public Application_SA[] Application_SA = new Application_SA[0];
```

Deserialized objects have no room to fit in.

Solution to this will be to switch to:

```
public List<Application_SA> Application_SA = new List<Application_SA>();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks.  I tried this, but there was no difference.  I am using the .Count property to check the number of occurrences of the Application_SA list and it returns zero.

Comment: Can you share working sample? I would like to deep dive into it and help.

Comment: I probably see the issue. Gimme a minute, I'll update the answer.

Comment: so this happened...a colleague suggested testing with this xml structure for the Application_SAList and it deserialzed into the array [].  However I can't tell the client to change their request xml.  must be something I can do to the classes to get it to work without the extra repeat tag:

Comment: <Application_SAList>
   <Application_SA>
   <Application_SA>
    <Account_Index>201921007322972</Account_Index>
    <Amount>50000.0</Amount>
    <App_Index>201921007322972</App_Index>
    <Percentage>100</Percentage>
    <Security_Key>1588</Security_Key>
       </Application_SA>
   </Application_SA>
  </Application_SAList>

Comment: the Application_SA tag is repeated

Comment: I got it. Wait a minute.

Comment: @gregorvoss: Answer updated. There is link to working solution on github. In case you need additional help just let me know!

Comment: I have found a solution.  in ApplicationRequestImpl.cs:[DataMember(Name="Application_SAList")]
        //public Application_SAList Application_SAList;
        public Application_SA[] Application_SA;

Comment: Or you can check mine solution without explicit DataMember attribute name.

Comment: You're welcome. I have been struggling with this too in the past. It is a bit tricky sometimes.